How customer gets an email receipt from Stripe after successful paymentIntent
I'm encountering an issue with sending a receipt email to customers from Stripe for successful confirmation of a PaymentIntent.
Here are the steps that I am following-

Create paymentIntent in stripe using below code.

    const paymentIntent = await stripeKey.paymentIntents.create({
            customer: customerId,
            setup_future_usage: 'off_session',
            amount: amount,
            currency: currencycode,
            receipt_email: customer.email,
            
        });


Using paymentIntenet client_secret to show paymentElement on UI.

    const appearance = {
       theme: 'stripe',
     };

    const options = {
      clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret,
      appearance,
    };

    elements = stripe.elements(options);
    paymentElement = elements.create("payment");
    paymentElement.mount("#payment-element");  


confirm PaymentIntent

    const response = await stripe.confirmPayment({
        elements,
        redirect:"if_required"
    });

Despite the successful debiting of the customer's account, I'm encountering an issue where customers are not receiving receipt emails from Stripe. I've verified that the email address associated with the customer is valid, and the option for sending successful payment receipts is enabled in the customer email settings within the Stripe dashboard.
what additional steps or modifications needed to do to ensure that customers receive receipts for their transactions?

If this is in livemode (as per Stripe docs, receipts will not be automatically sent in testmode), then it would probably be best to contact Stripe Support to figure out why.
